# mailserver for google apps email

Tags: g-suite, monit

My domain is using google apps email for its email hosting.  I was wondering if there was some way to connect to google email from my unix server so that I can send mail through that google apps account.

For example, monit (the server monitoring software package) will send mail to the local system using "set mailserver localhost"  Is there a way for me to replace localhost with some address from google apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty easy with [ssmtp](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/132006), here is [a wiki article](http://www.destr0yr.com/article.php/Gmail_and_sSMTP) talking about how to set up ssmtp on gentoo. While the location of the files might be different the configuration should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays gmail accounts and Google Apps all support outgoing SMTP. I'm not sure if it has to be enabled or not, I think it's enabled by default. The settings (for both) are:
Server: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
Use SSL
Username: google-apps-or-gmail@address
Passowrd: google-apps-or-gmail-password

Monit can be configured to use these settings as per [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/337742/sending-mails-with-monit-over-google-apps-mailserver) question:

```
set mailserver smtp.gmail.com PORT 587 USERNAME "info@mydomain.com" PASSWORD "mypassword" using TLSV1 with timeout 30 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can relay email via Google Apps if you have the Premium or Education package, not the free one.

Configure Google Apps to route outgoing mail to your SMTP server:

- Log in to the control panel to manage your domain at https://www.google.com/a/mydomain.com (change mydomain.com to your domain name)
- Select the Service Settings tab
- Select Email from the drop-down menu
- Add the IP address or hostname of your SMTP server to the Outbound gateway text box
- Configure postfix, exim, or sendmail on your local Unix server to relay everything via (I think) aspmx.l.google.com as the relay server.

Then, all your Unix server emails should go out via Google's relay

In theory you might be able to just add aspmx.l.google.com to monit instead of localhost.

Comment: That might work for un-authenticated relay. But if are wanting to relay mail through and mail server, all you need is an account on that mail server. Once you authenticate on the SMTP, you can send mail to whoever you want as whoever you want.

Comment: @Evan: relaying works also on regular (free) gmail accounts.