# Sending mails with monit over Google Apps mailserver

Tags: g-suite, monit

I am trying to send notification mails using monit v5.1. I am using Google Apps as a mailserver, so I wanted to use their infrastructure for outgoing mails.

I have entered the following information in my /etc/monit/monitrc:

```
set mailserver smtp.gmail.com PORT 587 USERNAME "info@mydomain.com" PASSWORT "mypassword" using TLSV1 with timeout 30 seconds
```

When monit tries to send out mails, I get the following error:

```
Sendmail error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.
```

How can I tell monit to use STARTTLS? How can I send alert mails via monit using the Google Apps mailserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for a reference if someone has the same problem... it was simply a spelling mistake, I should have used "PASSWORD" instead of "PASSWORT". Then everything works fine.